# "Can't locate PgCommon.pm" when trying to uninstall Postgres server

Tags: postgresql, perl, ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to remove `postgres` from my Ubuntu machine, but when I do, I'm getting the error message

```
Can't locate PgCommon.pm (@INC is [... a list of paths ...])
```

Any idea why PostgreSQL would lose track of a file it installed itself?

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if you changed Perl interpreters since installing `postgres`. It can't find the package anymore because it was installed into a different modules directory. If this command

```
$ which perl
```

doesn't give this response

```
/usr/bin/perl
```

It's likely that you're just using the wrong Perl binary. In my case, I had symlinked `/usr/local/bin/perl` to my custom Perl binary (which my app needs in order to function) so I just renamed the symlink temporarily, ran `apt-get remove postgres` again, then put the symlink back where it was!

Comment: Should have changed your app's shebang line rather than replacing `/usr/bin/perl`! (In fact, its installer should have done that for you.)

Comment: It would be wonderful if it were that easy. And in some cases (e.g., cronjobs) it is easy. But this is a huge legacy app that I've inherited, with tons of touch points, and presently, given the business' needs, there's not enough value in fixing all these hardcoded dependencies.

Comment: That's total garbage. It would have taken less long to fix the issue than to write this comment. Aside that it's should be done automatically by the installer (as the standard Perl installers do), a simple one liner can fix any number of files instantly. (And no, it's not easier to fix the shebang line of scripts called by cronjobs than other scripts.)

Comment: That is something that's open for debate, but please leave insults out of the debate.

Comment: Oh, also, I was confused about what installer you're referring to? The application I'm working with?

Comment: I don't know what insults. /// No, it's objective (measurable), not subjective (open to debate). /// MM and MB. No idea what installer you used to install your app.

Comment: I just felt like the 'That's total garbage' was unnecessary. Not that you were insulting me so much as the quality of the decisions I was making. There are a lot of decisions one has to triage in the course of the day, and sometimes what to the outside seems like an obvious choice might not be because of forces the outsider might not have considered. (E.g., more pressing matters than analyzing the most optimal way to get Perl working in an absolute mess of a codebase.) No installer; just a big lump of code that makes lots of assumptions about the environment.

Comment: No. I didn't comment on the quality of your decisions; I pointed out your claims are totally false. // Whatever you want to call the process of putting your program on a machine. That should have adusted the shebang lines.

Comment: "That should have adusted the shebang lines."

Would that I were so lucky :/ This is a pretty horrible app. The process of installing was `git clone ______`.

Comment: Time to add a second line!

Comment: Just a note that `perlbrew` (which is supposed to be the safer way to have non-system perls) will also get you into this mess. In that case, `perlbrew off` will get you back to the system perl for that specific session so that `apt` is happy. As someone who knows perl just fine, but postgres is very much a black box that apps require, this wasn't immediately obvious!